# Полносвязный граф на matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Есть программа, которая считает оптимальный путь (приближенный) и строит его на координатной плосткости (рисунок прилагается). Можно ли соединить все точки между собой еле заметными линиями, чтобы было видно, что это полносвязный граф, на котором красным выделяется оптимальный путь?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ниже привожу код отрисовки. Где nodes = [(x1,y1), (x2,y2), ... (xn, yn)], а best_path - собственно, оптимальный путь.

```
def plot(self, name=None):
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=100)
    x = [self.nodes[i][0] for i in self.best_path]
    x.append(x[0])
    y = [self.nodes[i][1] for i in self.best_path]
    y.append(y[0])
    plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=1, color='r')
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=30)
    plt.title(self.mode)
    for i in self.best_path
        plt.annotate(self.labels[i], self.nodes[i], size=11)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

nodes = [(1,2), (2,4), (3,3), (5,5)]

combs = list(combinations(nodes, 2))

x = list(chain(*[[p1[0],p2[0]] for p1,p2 in combs]))
y = list(chain(*[[p1[1],p2[1]] for p1,p2 in combs]))

plt.plot(x, y, marker='o')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS но лучше и проще воспользоваться модулем для работы с графами (например [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/)), которые умеет искать оптимальный путь и рисовать графы одной-двумя командами.